# What is the role of the Node ** list double pointer in the enqueue function for queues using linked list?

Tags: c, pointers, queue, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list

I was asked to implement a queue using a linked list without a header node. My teacher gave us this snippet for referring to the enqueue function. I'm familiar with how to use queue operations. But I keep getting confused when double-pointers are used along with functions. I'm not sure which variable the double-pointer points to in most cases. I would like to know what Node ** list means.

Any help or explanation is appreciated

Here is the snippet that I referred

```c
void insertNode(Node * prev,int x) {
    Node * new = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new->val = x;
    new->next = prev->next;
    prev->next = new;
}

void enqueue(Node ** list, int x) {
    Node * new = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (isEmpty(*list)) {
        *list = new;
        (*list)->val = x;
        (*list)->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        new = *list;
        while (new->next != NULL) 
            new = new->next;
        insertNode(new,x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Emulating *pass by reference*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is the very first time I've read that in this direction. I've heard the other direction, people calling pass-by-reference an emulation of pointers, many times!

Comment: Agree, pointers are the real deal, while references just try to hide the actual pointer to make it more readable, and unfortunately lose some of the capabilities in the process.

Comment: Fwiw, that enqueue could probably [be reduced](https://pastebin.com/a0sPJNkN). Note that managing a queue without *both* a front *and* back pointer is not efficient; especially if the queue has any respectable size. Walking the pointer chain to find the end for insertion is synonymous to [Schlemiel, The Painter](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm).

Comment: I just want to clarify one more doubt are we allowed to use **list = new instead of *list = new ?

Comment: Why would you want to? The types don't match. `**list` is `Node`, and `new` is `Node*`, so... *no*.

Comment: C doesn't have reference in the sense that many other languages have it. And it can only pass arguments by value. By using pointers and the pointer-to operator `&` you can emulate references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually double pointers as parameters of functions is used to modify the pointer itself.

Example:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;

void foo(int *x)
{
    x = &b;
}

void bar(int **x)
{
    *x = &b;
}


int main(void)
{
    int *ptr = &a;

    foo(ptr);
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);

    bar(&ptr);
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);
}
```

Output:

```
5
10
```

Function `bar` modifies the pointer `ptr`.
Function `foo` does not as x is a local variable having the function scope.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function `enqueue` is wrong. It can produce a memory leak.

At first a node was allocated dynamically and its address was assigned to the pointer `new`

```
Node * new = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

and then the pointer was reassigned by the value of  the pointer expression `*list`

```
    new = *list;
```

So the address of the earlier dynamically allocated memory is lost.

Moreover the functions `insertNode` and `enqueue` are unsafe. If memory for the new node was not allocated then the functions invoke undefined behavior.

The both functions should be declared and defined the following way

```
int insertNode( Node * prev,int x ) 
{
    Node *new = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    int success = new != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new->val = x;
        new->next = prev->next;
        prev->next = new;
    }

    return success;
}
```

and

```
int enqueue( Node **list, int x ) 
{
    if ( isEmpty( *list ) ) 
    {
        Node *new = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
        int success = new != NULL;

        if ( success )
        {
            new->val = x;
            new->next = NULL;
            *list = new;
        }

        return success;
    }
    else 
    {
        Node *current = *list;
        while ( current->next != NULL ) current = current->next;
        return insertNode( current, x );
    }
}
```

As for your question then the function `enqueue` can change the pointer to the head node when the lost is empty.

So the pointer must be passed to the function by reference.

In C passing by reference means passing an object (pointer is also an object) indirectly through a pointer to it. Thus dereferencing the pointer like for example

```
*list = new;
```

the function get an access to the original object (or pointer) and can change its value.

Otherwise relative to your function `enqueue` the passed pointer will be passed by value. And in this case the function will deal with a copy of the value of the original pointer. Changing the copy of the value of the original pointer will not change the original pointer. It will still unchanged. It is the copy of the value of the original pointer that will be changed within the function.